# MenuItem must be inside a form element BUT Form already exist

Tags: jsf, primefaces, xhtml

I'm working on primefaces and i can't understand this error.

My all xhtml code
My xhtml code :

```
<ui:composition template="/layout/template.xhtml"
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
            xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
            xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
            xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
            xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
            >
<ui:define name="content">
    <h:form id="formTab"> 
        <p:commandButton value="Ajouter" oncomplete="PF('addNewDialog').show()" />
        <p:dataTable var="tasktype" value="#{taskTypeBean.allTaskTypes}" id="taskType" selection="#{taskTypeBean.selectedTaskType}" selectionMode="single" rowKey="#{tasktype.reference}">
            <p:column headerText="Reference">
                <h:outputText value="#{tasktype.reference}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="Description">
                <h:outputText value="#{tasktype.description}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="Prix Hors Taxe">
                <h:outputText value="#{tasktype.htPrice}" />
            </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>

        <p:contextMenu for="taskType">
            <p:menuitem value="Modifier" action="#{taskTypeBean.updateDialog()}"  update=":updateForm:udpatePanel" />
            <p:menuitem value="Supprimer" action="#{taskTypeBean.deleteTaslType()}" update="taskType" />
        </p:contextMenu>
    </h:form>

    <p:dialog widgetVar="updateDialog" modal="true" appendTo="@(body)">
        <h:form id="updateForm">
            <p:growl id="growlModif" showDetail="true" sticky="true" /> 
            <p:panelGrid  columns="2" id="udpatePanel">
                <p:outputLabel for="reference" value="Reference :"/>
                <p:inputText id="reference" required="true" requiredMessage="Entrez une reference" disabled="true" value="#{taskTypeBean.taskToUpdate.reference}"/> 
                <p:outputLabel for="description" value="Description :"/>
                <p:inputText id="description" required="true" requiredMessage="Entrez une description" value="#{taskTypeBean.taskToUpdate.description}"/> 
                <p:outputLabel for="HTprice" value="HTprice :"/>
                <p:inputText id="HTprice" required="true" requiredMessage="Entrez un prix hors taxe" value="#{taskTypeBean.taskToUpdate.htPrice}"/> 
                <p:commandButton value="Modifier" id="modifier" action="#{taskTypeBean.updateTaskType}" update=":formTab:taskType" oncomplete="PF('updateDialog').hide()" styleClass="ui-priority-primary" />
            </p:panelGrid>
        </h:form>
    </p:dialog>


    <p:dialog widgetVar="addNewDialog" modal="true" appendTo="@(body)">
        <h:form>
            <p:growl id="growlAdd" showDetail="true" sticky="true" /> 
            <p:panelGrid  columns="2">
                <p:outputLabel for="reference" value="Reference :"/>
                <p:inputText id="reference" required="true" requiredMessage="Entrez une reference" value="#{taskTypeBean.newReference}"/> 
                <p:outputLabel for="description" value="Description :"/>
                <p:inputText id="description" required="true" requiredMessage="Entrez une description" value="#{taskTypeBean.newDescription}"/> 
                <p:outputLabel for="HTprice" value="HTprice :"/>
                <p:inputText id="HTprice" required="true" requiredMessage="Entrez un prix hors taxe" value="#{taskTypeBean.newHTprice}"/> 
                <p:commandButton value="Ajouter" id="ajouter" action="#{taskTypeBean.addNewTaskType}" update=":formTab:taskType" oncomplete="PF('addNewDialog').hide()" styleClass="ui-priority-primary" />
            </p:panelGrid>
        </h:form>
    </p:dialog>


</ui:define>
```

There is 3 differents form in this page

So, we can see  and i have this issue :

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: MenuItem must be inside a form element
javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:606)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

I built this page with an template very basic, i can't understand this problem.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Can you post the whole XHTML file and not just the snippet.  I feel like something has to be wrong somewhere because based on your snippet it should be fine. So something else must be wrong.

Comment: I updated my post

Comment: Hmm that looks OK.  Now it has me wondering if you just temporarily remove your `p:contextMenu` does the error go away or do you get a different error?  Are we positive its those menu items and not something in your template.xhtml you are extending?

Comment: I tried to remove it, but i had an other issue which is that an propertie "update" cannot find my Form.

Comment: I think my xhtml cannot reconize my form....

Comment: class com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.UIInstructions cannot be cast to class org.primefaces.model.menu.MenuElement

Comment: Yeah you definitely have something core fundamentally messed up with this project. Your XHTML looks OK to me so its almost like something else like libraries or configuration or something else is messed up with your setup.

Comment: My suggestion here would be to step back and see if you can reproduce this behavior with a minimal backing bean and minimal XHTML page.

Then post that code here.

Comment: @AdamWaldenberg: via [ mcve ] without the space you can reference [mcve]

Comment: Please post version info. Iirc an older version of PF had the issue about the classcast. @Melloware: please never ask about the full xhtml but a [mcve] instead